# WiFi Router stops providing internet connection when WiFi router plugged into 1GB Network Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-router

When my WiFi router is connected to the ISP modem to receive internet, I am able to connect to the WiFI network and have internet access; however, when I connect the WiFi router to our network switch, the WiFi router can no longer connect to the internet.

This is a new issue; up until a few days ago, internet access was working through the WiFI router and the network switch (connected via ehternet cable to the WiFi router).

Does this mean there is something wrong with the network switch?

Comment: Has the switch been rebooted ? If the switch configuration had not been saved and it was powered off, it is possible that some configurations would be lost (especially if there are vLANs configured in the switch to split networks). - You need to check in the switch configuration.

Comment: It always helps it you tell us the equipment involved. Just saying it's a network switch does not really tell us anything. Who is the manufacturer & what is the model?

Comment: it is a TrendNet 1GB POE switch